# Java/swing font resize not working across platforms

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jcomponent

I have a swing application with this code, which attempts to resize the font of a component:

```
Font f = new Font(Font.SERIF,Font.PLAIN,16);
component.setFont(f);
```

The program loads with 14 point font, and I include a component which lets the user resize the component to 16 point font as above. When I run this on the computer I compiled it on (Debian), it works as intended, but I tested it on a Mac and a Windows computer and the font resizing feature doesn't work at all. However, on all platforms the font is serif. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The question is already asked: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11997304/1340559) could help you.

Comment: Not really; the person there was asking for the exact same font across all platforms. Whatever serif font on a platform is fine to me, but I just want a way to resize the font (i.e. the application loads with 14 point font. when I set the font size to 16 on debian using a component which lets the user choose the font, the font resizes, but when I set it to 16 on windows, nothing happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component's default UI delegate on your platform may be pre-empting your setting. In the alternative, consider one of the following:

- Use `deriveFont()` on the existing font, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513).

  ```
  component.getFont().deriveFont(16f)
  ```
- Use an available `sizeVariant`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).

[image: size variant]

- Use a custom UI delegate, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513).

[image: custom UI delegate]