# How to change font size on a desktop Java application?

Tags: java, font-size

I wrote a program, exported it as ".jar" and ran it on a computer other than my developer desktop PC. The problem arose that the entire JFrame on the laptop was smaller and therefore certain texts were replaced with "..." because the component was too small to display it completely. Now the question arises is there the possibility to change my text size dynamically that it is always getting displayed completely?

Edit 1:
My problem is that I first have to get the font size at which my text is replaced by "...".

|that is the code|
[image: |that is the code]

|that is how the gui should look (It looks like this on my desktop pc)|
[image: |that is how the gui should look]

|that is how the gui looks on my laptop|
[image: that is how the gui looks on my laptop]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java/swing font resize not working across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235228/java-swing-font-resize-not-working-across-platforms)

Comment: @MarcK I will try it out... Answer in 10 mins

Comment: @MarcK the solution did not worked out.

Comment: @HansWurst try to find out a good scale of font-size to component size. Check which size the component actually is in your code and adjust the font-size according to the component size.

Comment: Alternatively, use a layout manager to scale the label to its content, not the other way around.

Comment: @codeflush.dev thied what you said, but it did not work

Comment: @Taschi yes I think thats the only way how to do it...

Comment: In the case of the screenshot, you could also just add a few extra pixels to the label - there's plenty of space to the left and right, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really a solution to the problem but I know what was the fault. My windows was scaled to 125% so some text dissapeared...